# How can I run a php script 24/7?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php script which generates random values for two different variables in a different interval. I need to have this script run 24/7 and in the background (page must be closed). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on your operating system use either cron (linux/unix/mac) or scheduled tasks (windows) to run the script repeatedly on a recurring schedule.

Comment: You can write a loop and run the script with `php script.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to configure a cron job to resolve your problem. Loop in php is not good enought for this, as practice shows, because if php loop script just end with error it will never start again without your help.

Answer (score 0):

Write an infinite loop and run the PHP file on the server.

```
while(true){
  // generates random values for two different variables in a different interval
}
```